# Stringdb using R Bioconductor package

Tags: database, data, protein-interaction, network

I need to retreive a large dataset from String-db. 
I 'm newbie in R so even with the documentation , I could not get the dataset fron String 
How do I do to retreive a network from String 2k to 3k proteins 
what are the functions  to use for such matter  ?

Comment: I think this question belongs to [SO]

Answer (score 0):

String uses [REST API](https://string-db.org/cgi/access.pl), although the link to the help page for that results in a blank page instead (contact the authors!). In general, I would use the API. Alternatively, just download the database locally, they have a [quite neat collection ready to be downloaded](https://string-db.org/cgi/download.pl)

Comment: If I donwload it locally  , I can retreive 200k proteins ? and download the network I need right ?

Comment: Correct. Check the download page, they have different "packets" download the one you are interested in.

Comment: Okay I'm downloading the first packet in the interaction data section  for homosapien. What I don't get is that how am I going to use it ?  how would I know the proteins or the specific network for cacaner ?

Comment: It has 11353057 interaction , I have no Idea how to get only cancer network ?

Comment: You need to have list of protein you are interested in. There is no shuch a thing like a "cancer network" you may find different databases online, like the COSMIC, that lists genes found to be linked with cancer. You can start there. But this goes beyond your question.

Comment: Now I have alist of proteins of interest how do I proceed ? Is there any tool I can use to gget the 200k I need

Comment: If don't know how to start then please take time to study and try out. This forum is not meant to ask other people to do your job. One thing is if you have a particular question,  but you are asking to solve a rather complex bio information problem without knowing the basics. Now you have a database and a list of proteins of interest. Write down what is that you want to know about them and use the database to answer your questions. If you don't know how to do that than step back and start studying how to query a database with R.

Comment: Well thank you for clarifications, Actually I did and I used R to retreive neighbors , which got me 5827 mapping identifier, with 3916 interaction. yet I need more like 200k  mapping identifier to work with . and I have no clue how to proceed as the resources are so limited down there

Comment: Try ask on https://www.biostars.org It's specific for bioinformatics.